# TestFlight internal testers and UDID

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, testflight, udid

I know that external TestFlight doesn't need to add their UDID.
Is this a requirement for internal testers? Or can those be added without a UDID as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No internal testers are also not required to add their UDID. Only Add their apple ID and request them to test.